# Using !s vs. :s to format a string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm really curious about `:s` format string in Python 3. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) says `!s` is **conversion** and that `:s` is `format_spec`.

It also says `!s` will apply `str()`, but it doesn't say anything similar about `:s`. I think there's no significant difference between them, but I want to be sure. Can anyone clarify these?

Some code example:

```
print("{!s}".format("this"))
print("{:s}".format("that"))
# I want to be sure that these two are processed identically internally
```

It's still confusing, but let me wrap up with my own (layperson's) words.

1. `type("whatever".format)` is always `str`.
2. Use `!s` if you want convert the object into `str` before formatting.
3. `:s` means that the object(or the converted object) will be treated as `str` during some internal formatting process. It's the default `format_spec`.

Is anything wrong here?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`!s`, and its brethren `!a` and `!r` apply `str()`, `ascii()` and `repr()` respectively **before** interpolation and formatting. These are called *conversion flags*, and are part of the [*Format String Syntax* spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), not the [per-field formatting spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) applied to values when interpolating:

> The *conversion* field causes a type coercion **before formatting**. Normally, the job of formatting a value is done by the `__format__()` method of the value itself. **However, in some cases it is desirable to force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own definition of formatting.** By converting the value to a string before calling `__format__()`, the normal formatting logic is bypassed.

Bold emphasis mine.

`:s` only applies afterwards to the conversion result (or the original object if no conversion had been applied), and only if the `__format__` method for the type of object supports that formatting option. Usually, only objects of type `str` support this formatter; it's there as the default, mostly because the [*Format Specification Mini-Language*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) allows for the existence of a type character and because the older  [`%` `printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting) had a `%s` format. If you tried to apply the `s` type to an object that doesn't support it, you'd get an exception.

Use `!s` (or `!a` or `!r`) when you have an object that is not itself a string and either doesn't support formatting otherwise (not all types do) or would format differently from their `str()`, `ascii()` or `repr()` conversions:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "Foo as a string"
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "<Foo as repr, with åéæ some non-ASCII>"
...     def __format__(self, spec):
...         return "Foo formatted to {!r} spec".format(spec)
...
>>> print("""\
... Different conversions applied:
... !s: {0!s:>60s}
... !r: {0!r:>60s}
... !a: {0!a:>60s}
... No conversions: {0:>50s}
... """.format(Foo()))
Different conversions applied:
!s:                                    Foo as a string
!r:             <Foo as repr, with åéæ some non-ASCII>
!a:    <Foo as repr, with \xe5\xe9\xe6 some non-ASCII>
No conversions: Foo formatted to '>50s' spec
```

Note: *all* formatting specified by the format spec are the responsibility of the `__format__` method; the last line does not apply the alignment operation in the `>50s` formatting spec, the `Foo.__format__` method only used it as literal text in a formatting operation (using a `!r` conversion here).

For the converted values, on the other hand, the `str.__format__` method is used and the output is aligned to the right in a 50 character wide field, padded with spaces on the left.

Answer (score 3):

You're unlucky you used strings as the value to be formatted. Using pretty much any other object you'd get how these aren't the same.

In (as much as I can) layman's terms:

- The absence or existence of the conversion flag specifies *the type of the value we going to format* and, by extent, who's `__format__` we'll be calling. As Martjin points out, by using this we can bypass certain behavior and treat the value more generically (like a string). It comes in three different flavors that correspond to the three different ways an object can choose to represent itself as a string.
- The type specifier, coupled with other specifiers, specifies *how the type we have should finally be presented*. For strings there isn't a rich set of options (a string is presented as is) but, for types like `int`s, you can have different presentations.

I do think, though, that `type` is probably a confusing name to give this specifier.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation, *[Python String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)*:

> The field_name is optionally followed by a conversion field, which is preceded by an exclamation point '!', and a format_spec, which is preceded by a colon ':'.

So no, it's not the same.

For example:

If you want to print a float as a string, you need a conversion (float → string).

```
"{!s}".format(2.1457)
>>> 2.1457
type("{!s}".format(2.1457))
>>> <type 'str'>
```

If you don't use the conversion mark, you will get an error.

```
"{:s}".format(2.1457)
>>> ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'float'
```

Comment: "Conversion field" speaks for itself.

Comment: `"..".format(..)` is **always** a string. Your `type()` demo makes little sense in this context, as it will *always be the same* regardless of what formatting specs or conversions have been applied to the formatted objects.

Comment: Also, there are other format spec types that'll raise exceptions, even when you applied a `!s` conversion, like `i`.