# Difference between colon and exclamation point

Tags: python

In Python 3 is there a difference between `{0:s}` and `{0!s}` when used in a print statement? For example:

```
print("Hello {0:s} and {0!s}".format('foo'))
```

prints out the same thing twice.

From the documentation it says:

> The *field_name* is optionally followed by a conversion field, which is preceded by an exclamation point `'!'`, and a *format_spec*, which is preceded by a colon `':'`. These specify a non-default format for the replacement value.

Does that mean `!` is like casting?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax. Also print _isn't_ a statement in Python 3 (hasn't been since v2), and the fact that the formatted string gets passed to print isn't relevant to the behaviour.

Comment: I am really confused then.  I'm using spider 5.+ and print() works fine.  What exactly do you mean that print isn't a statement?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: Or even more directly https://stackoverflow.com/q/41630728/3001761